# Check NSMutableDictionary for values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm making an API Calls which contain live information. This can 2 types of information. If there is information it will return something like this:

```
goaltype = "Regular goal";
id = 2787821;
minute = 45;
player = Nono;
"player_id" = 317569;
playershort = Nono;
team = "Real Betis";
"team_id" = 8603;
```

If there is no information it will return:

```
error = "no live games found"
```

If it returns error my tableview will at the moment count the error message as 1 object and return 1 cell. So if the results return error, then it should not run the loop. How can i obtain this or is there another way?

my code:

```
NSDictionary* headers = @{@"X-Mashape-Authorization": @"MASHAPEKEY"};
NSDictionary* parameters = @{};

UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response = [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest* request) {
    [request setUrl:@"https://willjw-statsfc-competitions.p.mashape.com/live.json?key=APIKEY&competition=premier-league&timezone=Europe%2FLondon"];

    [request setHeaders:headers];
    [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];


NSData* rawBody = [response rawBody];
results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawBody options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];




for (int i = 0; i <= results.count-1; i++)
{


    NSString *homeTeam = [[results valueForKey:@"homeshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *awayTeam = [[results valueForKey:@"awayshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *time = [[results valueForKey:@"statusshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *homeScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *awayScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:1]];


    [arrayBarclay addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:homeTeam,@"hometeam", awayTeam,@"awayteam", time, @"time", homeScore, @"homescore", awayScore, @"awayscore", nil]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What NeverHopeless said… plus… (much simpler syntax)

```
if (![result valueForKey:@"error"]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++) {
        NSString *homeTeam = results[@"home short"][i];
        NSString *awayTeam = results[@"awayshort"][i];
        NSString *time = results[@"statusshort"][i];
        NSString *homeScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", results[@"runningscore"][i][0];
        NSString *awayScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", results[@"runningscore"][i][1];
        [arrayBarclay addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@[
            @"hometeam":homeTeam, 
            @"awayteam":awayTeam,
            @"time":time,
            @"homescore":homeScore,
            @"awayscore":awayScore]
        ];
    }
}
```

(I would have posted this as a comment on NeverHopeless's answer except that comments lose formatting.)

Answer (score 3):

If no sight of `error` key that means you are getting expected data, so iterating on resultset is expected to be safe.

```
if(![result valueForKey:@"error"])
{
for (int i = 0; i <= results.count-1; i++)
{


    NSString *homeTeam = [[results valueForKey:@"homeshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *awayTeam = [[results valueForKey:@"awayshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *time = [[results valueForKey:@"statusshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *homeScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *awayScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:1]];


    [arrayBarclay addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:homeTeam,@"hometeam", awayTeam,@"awayteam", time, @"time", homeScore, @"homescore", awayScore, @"awayscore", nil]];

}
}
```

Comment: Thats strange ![result valueForKey:@"error"] does not trigger and there is no key called error